# Android ViewPager + custom adapter lag

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm creating an activity that have a ViewPager, and inside the ViewPager there are 5 tabs/fragments. I'm also implementing FragmentPagerAdapter like below :

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return fragmentA;
                case 1:
                    return fragmentB;
                case 2:
                    return fragmentC;
                case 3:
                    return  fragmentD;
                case 4:
                    return fragmentE;
                default:
                    return fragmentA;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return numberOfPage;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabTitle[position];
        }
    }
```

the code above only display the fragment and initialize the view without populating data into the listview , to populate data into listview I used the code below :

```
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    switch (position){
                        case 0:
                            fragmentA.requestDataFromServer();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            fragmentB.requestDataFromServer();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            fragmentC.requestDataFromServer();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            break;
                        default:
                           break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

and the requestDataFromServer() :

```
public void requestDataFromServer(){
    new Thread(new Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            //below is volley request
            ApiServer.getInstance().requestData(getContext(),new JsonResponseCb{
                @Override
                public onSuccess(Object res){

                    new Thread(new Runnable{
                        list.addAll((List<Example>)res);
                    }).start();

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                @Override
                public onFail(Object res){}
                @Override
                public onError(Object res){}

            });
        }

    }).start();

}
```

requestData() code :

```
public void requestData(final Context context, final JsonResponseCb cb)
    {
        LogHelper.debug(getClass(),"Outside thread = "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        if (cb == null || context == null)
            return;
        apiServerRequest(context, Constants.getNFUrl(), null, new ApiServer.ServerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final JSONObject jsonObject) {
                NfResponse response = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), NfResponse.class);
                if(response.getStatus() != null && response.getStatus().equals("OK"))
                    cb.onSuccess(response.getNewsfeedPost());
                else
                    cb.onFail(null);

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VolleyError error) {

            }
        },Request.Method.GET);
    }
```

apiServerRequest() code :

```
private void apiServerRequest(Context context, String url, Map<String, Object> bodyParameter, final ServerCallback serverCallback, int method) {
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        if (bodyParameter == null) {
            final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(method, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    serverCallback.onSuccess(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    serverCallback.onError(error);
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(Constants.SERVER_TIMEOUT, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        } else {
            final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(method, url, new JSONObject(bodyParameter), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    serverCallback.onSuccess(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    serverCallback.onError(error);
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(Constants.SERVER_TIMEOUT, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        }

    }
```

I have already run a different thread to populate data, but it still says

```
Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I used custom Adapter for the listview and I've implemented ViewHolder pattern on the adapter.

Any solution to this?

Comment: is ExampleList some subtype of List? Maybe you parse the server response on the main Thread?

Comment: @Droidman I've updated my question, I do all the parsing inside new Thread

Comment: no you don't from what I can see in your code. What you actually do is *requesting* the data on some worker Thread. Since the request is asynchronous, the onSuccess callback later runs on the main Thread

Comment: @Droidman can you show me how to make the callback runs on new Thread?

Comment: see my answer, I hope the small example I just tested will help you understand what is actually going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What is happening?*

You actually only send your request on a background `Thread` whilst the `onSuccess` callback runs later on the main `Thread` thus causing the lag. To illustrate this, here's a small example:

```
final RequestQueue q = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
q.start();
    new Thread((new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.w("Thread:", Thread.currentThread().getName()); // Thread-13 in my test-case
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
                   Request.Method.GET, 
                   "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", 
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { // <-- your onSuccess callback
                    Log.e("Thread:", Thread.currentThread().getName()); // main
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Thread:", Thread.currentThread().getName()); // main
                }
            });
            q.add(request); // roughly equivalent to your requestData call
        }
    })).start();
```

*How to prevent it from happening?*

You should start a worker `Thread` to process the server response **after** you get this response.

Try the following:

```
public void requestData(final Context context, final JsonResponseCb cb)
{
    LogHelper.debug(getClass(),"Outside thread = "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    if (cb == null || context == null)
        return;
    apiServerRequest(context, Constants.getNFUrl(), null, new ApiServer.ServerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final JSONObject jsonObject) {
          new Thread(() -> {
            NfResponse response = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), NfResponse.class);
              if(response.getStatus() != null && response.getStatus().equals("OK"))
               cb.onSuccess(response.getNewsfeedPost());
              else
               cb.onFail(null);
      }).start();
    }

        @Override
        public void onError(VolleyError error) {

        }
    },Request.Method.GET);
}
```

**Note** that in this case, the `onSuccess` callback will be called on a background Thread and you should wrap any UI operations you need to perform from this callback into

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // your UI code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried to log and it's true that the callback runs on main. So I created a new thread to parse the callback response, but the lagging still persists :(

Comment: please update your code and show *all places* where you parse data

Comment: I've updated my question, I don't put notifyDataSetChanged() inside the new thread since the new thread can't touch the view

Comment: Please show the requestData method from the ApiServer class

Comment: it seems the lag is caused either by `gson.fromJson` or `response.getNewsfeedPost` (or both) method(s) running on the main Thread. What I'm trying to do is to find where the actual JSON parsing happens since this must definitely be moved to a background Thread

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154867/discussion-between-vincenttheonardo-and-droidman).